# Acra ReportSender can not start IntentService

Tags: android, acra

I try a pregnancy app.
I used first time ACRA.
I have chosen to use reportsend interface.
My problem ReportSender page is working but I want a IntentService but its not working.

ErrorReportingService.java

```
public class ErrorReportingService extends IntentService {

    public ErrorReportingService() {
        super("ErrorReportingService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.d( "geldimihat","Servis" );

    }
}
```

ErrorLogSender.java

```
public class ErrorLogSender implements ReportSender {

    private Context context;

    public ErrorLogSender(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void send(CrashReportData report) throws ReportSenderException {

        Intent intentservice    = new Intent( context, ErrorReportingService.class);
        context.startService( intentservice );
    }
}
```

ApplicationManager.java

```
@ReportsCrashes(
        formKey = "1234",
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
        resToastText = R.string.read_more)
public class ApplicationManager extends Application {

    private static ApplicationManager instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        ACRA.init(this);
        ErrorLogSender errorLogSender = new ErrorLogSender( ApplicationManager.this );
        ACRA.getErrorReporter().setReportSender( errorLogSender );
        instance = this;
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
    }

}
```

AndroidManifes.xml

```
<service android:name="com.tupbebekailesi.medyasef.hamilelikrehberi.ErrorReportingService"></service>
```

This Codes Not starting IntentService.

Please help